# Solving Systems of ODEs using Octave

Tags: octave

```
>>function dxdt = fff(x,t)
  %constants and parameters
  u=0;
  %equations
  dxdt(1)=0.11*x(3)/(0.006*x(1)+x(3))*x(1)-u*x(1)/(500*x(4));
  dxdt(2)=0.0055*x(3)/(0.001+x(3)*(1+10*x(3)))*x(2)-0.01*x(2)-u*x(2)/(500*x(4));
  dxdt(3)=-(h1*x(1)/0.47+0.0055*x(3)/(0.001+x(3)(1+10*x(3)))*x(1)/1.2+x(1)*x(3)*0.029/(0.001+x(3)))+(1-x(3)/500)*u/x(4);
  dxdt(4)=u/500;
  dxdt=dxdt';
endfunction

>>[x,t]=ode45(@dxdt,[1.5 0 0 7]',[0 120])

error: x(3): out of bound 1
error: called from
dxdt at line 5 column 10
starting_stepsize at line 46 column 5
ode45 at line 192 column 25
```

The above errors pop up when I execute the code. x0=[1.5 0 0 7]' and t has the range from 0 to 120. I saved the dxdt.m and selected the right directory. Would anyone have a clue for what is wrong with the code? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be calling your arguments the other way round. From the documentation:

```
 -- [T, Y] = ode45 (FUN, TRANGE, INIT)

     FUN is a function handle, inline function, or string containing the
     name of the function that defines the ODE: 'y' = f(t,y)'.  The
     function must accept two inputs where the first is time T and the
     second is a column vector of unknowns Y.
```

Also note the fact that it expects a 'column' vector. Not sure if this is important, but it might explain why it complains it only has '1' index  (since what you're passing only has '1' row).

Comment: Thank you for your help. I changed the parameters but it still does not seem to work. Any ideas? Also, I believe that we can define our own parameters and variables for the function, right?

Comment: "Does not seem to work" doesn't give much information to work with ... would you like to update your question with the new code and error messages?

Comment: Also, not quite. The specification of the `f` function needs to be adhered to for use within `ode45`. If you want to use a function with a _different_ signature, you would have to "wrap" with an anonymous function first.